# Dynamic Select Menu Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a dynamic select menu using this [guide](http://pullmonkey.com/2012/08/11/dynamic-select-boxes-ruby-on-rails-3/); however, it doesn't seem to be changing the select select statement.

Here is what I have as far as code:

```
#characters_controller.rb
    def new
        @skills = Skill.all
        @classes = Classe.all
        @background = Background.all
        @character = Character.new
    end
    def update_classe_skills
        classe = Classe.find(params[:character][:classe_id])

        @skills = classe.skills.map{|a| [a.name,a.name]}.insert(0,"Select a Skill")
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end


#routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :characters
    get 'characters/update_classe_skills', :as => 'update_classe_skills'
end
```

This is the .js.erb file:

```
#update_classe_skills.js.erb

$('#character_classe_skill_option_one').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@skills)) %>");
```

This is my AJAX script:

```
#skills_select_handler.js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change','#character_classe_id', function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "#{update_classe_skills_path}",
        data: {
          classe_id : $('#character_classe_id').val()
        },
        dataType: "script",
        type: 'GET'
      });
    });
 });
```

And lastly, this is my select menu:

```
#new.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "skills_select_handler.js"  %>
<%= form_for :character, url: characters_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    <%= render :partial => "info_step", :locals => {:f => f} %>
    <%= render :partial => "rand_prompt_step", :locals => {:f => f} %>
    <%= render :partial => "skills_step", :locals => {:f => f}%>
<% end %>
#_info_step.html.erb
<p>
    <%= f.label :classe_id, "Class" %><br>
    <%= f.select :classe_id, options_for_select([["Barbarian", 1], ["Bard", 2], ["Cleric", 3], ["Druid", 4], ["Fighter", 5], ["Monk", 6], ["Paladin", 7], ["Ranger", 8], ["Rogue", 9], ["Sorcerer", 10], ["Warlock", 11], ["Wizard", 12]], selected: "#{@character.classe_id}"), include_blank: true, id:'character_classe_id' %>
    <span><%= @character.errors[:classe_id][0] %></span>
</p>

#_skills_step.html.erb
<div id="classe_skill_proficiency_one">
    <p>
        <%= f.label :classe_skill_option_one, "Skill Proficiency" %>
        <br>
        <%= f.collection_select(:classe_skill_option_one, @skills, :name, :name,{:prompt   => "Select a Skill"}, {id: 'character_classe_skill_option_one'})%>
    </p>
</div>
```

I used to have all the partials rendered off the 'new' view, however, that wasn't working. I've tried troubleshooting it myself, so things may have gotten a little wonky.

When I look at the server console after changing the class, I do see the following:

```
Processing by CharactersController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"classe_id"=>"1", "_"=>"1454977094482"}
  [list of stuff being loaded and rendered]
  Skill Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "skills".* FROM "skills"
```

So that leads me to believe it is leading as far as the AJAX request, but then just loads the entire skill list instead of the the skills joined to the particular class.

The join tables are made correctly, so that is not the issue.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get the select menu to change it's options?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :characters
  get "update_classe_skills/:classe_id", as: 'update_classe_skills', on: :collection #-> url.com/characters/update_classe_skills/:classe_id
end

#skills_select_handler.js
$(document).on("change","#character_classe_id", function(e) {
  var classe_id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
     url: "characters/update_classe_skills/" + classe_id,
     data: { classe_id : classe_id },
     dataType: "script",
     type: 'GET'
   });
 });

 #app/controllers/characters_controller.rb
 class CharactersController < ApplicationController

    def update_classe_skills
      @classe = Classe.find params[:classe_id]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end          
    end

end

#app/views/characters/update_classe_skills.js.erb
$('select#character_classe_skill_option_one').empty.append("<%=j options_from_collection_for_select(@skills, 'name', 'name') %>");
```

---

I believe you have several errors in your code:

1. Your `ajax` URL is reliant in a JS value (`classe_id`), yet you don't have it
2. Your `update_classe_skills` JS doesn't update the `select` (only the container `div`)
3. Your controller method was inefficient

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. It ended up being a route issue.

I changed the following:

```
#characters_controller.rb
def update_classe_skills
    classe = Classe.find(params[:classe_id])

    @skills = classe.skills.map{|a| [a.name,a.name]}.insert(0,"Select a Skill")
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end


#skills_select_handler.js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change','#character_classe_id', function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/update_classe_skills",
        data: {
          classe_id : $('#character_classe_id').val()
        },
        dataType: "script",
        type: 'GET'
      });
    });
 });

#routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :characters
    match "/update_classe_skills", :to => "characters#update_classe_skills", :via => [:get]
end
```

I also had to add `protect_from_forgery_except :update_classe_skills` to my characters controller.

The reason why this was happening is because of the show route generated by `resources :characters` in my routes. It was looking for `/characters/:id` and therefore my route was being processed as show route, and getting no results since there was no `:id => "update_classe_skills"`